# How to keep hash or remove it from url - node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have some local anchors on the main page. When I click the link with "/#anchor1" it scrolls to the corresponding part. Fine.
Now I refresh the page. It cuts hash from url, okay, and redirects to the main page. But! Hash is not removed completely from url, not it's /anchor1, and if I refresh the page one more time I will be redirected to 404 because I don't have any "anchor1" route of course.

How get rid of this behavior? It doesn't matter for me if hash is still in url, or cut completely but definitely it should NOT appear there without the hash symbol.
Thanks!

UPD
I really didn't solve this problem but I found some workaround that I can accept right now. After I add the hashtag and scroll to the corresponding section I remove this hash tag, I use angular:

```
$location.hash('');
```

Comment: is it possible if you add the hash url to the route? when it gets requested you can do a redirect to the page you want or you can just use `window.location.href` in the browser?

Comment: Do you have multiple hash values in your URL?  The browser should not be dropping the hash segment of a valid URL upon refresh so if it is, then it must be detecting something wrong with the format of the URL.

Comment: @turmuka, do you mean to add the hash itself to the route? Hmm it probably would work but I wouldn't like to add all the hashes that I'm using over the whole web service... maybe there is some another solution?

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm not sure what you mean "multiple". The url can be like "mysite.com/#features" or "mysite.com/#pricing", that's it.